# Unable to use Composer (for Drush) on Bluehost - install problem

Tags: composer

I apparently successfully installed Composer (for use with Drush) on bluehost. See messages below. It does not work, however. When I type composer.phar I get nothing or "command not found" among other error messages. See below.

I am a newbie so it may be that install worked just fine, but I just don't know how to properly execute composer to make sure it works.

I am using instructions found at http://avantidevelopment.com/install-composer-on-bluehost/ & https://www.drupal.org/node/2366283.

```
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/bin]# cd ~
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~]# mkdir ~/common
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~]# cd ~/common
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /home5/columck5/common/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# which php-cli
/usr/bin/php-cli
PHP Version     5.4.24


columck5@columbiablooms.org [/ramdisk/php/54/bin]# cd ~/common
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# ls -l
total 1164

drwxr-xr-x  2 columck5 columck5    4096 Oct 29 08:37 ./

drwx--x--- 21 columck5 nobody      4096 Oct 28 09:15 ../

-rwxr-xr-x  1 columck5 columck5 1176136 Oct 29 08:37 composer.phar*

-rw-r--r--  1 columck5 columck5     575 Oct 29 08:38 error_log

columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# composer.phar

-bash: composer.phar: command not found

columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# composer
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# php composer

Status: 404 Not Found
Content-type: text/html

No input file specified.

columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# php-cli composer.phar
columck5@columbiablooms.org [~/common]# php-cli composer

Could not open input file: composer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content-type:text-html means your script is running from CGI instead of CLI.

so try to fix your install so that the PHP in the path uses a CLI

One simple way to do is to write php path to php-cli instead of php-cgi.

```
# .bash_profile
export DRUSH_PHP=/ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli
```

Comment: Sorry to be such a dummy, but the export line should be inserted as the last line of .bash_profile? There is so much to learn when trying to build a site using Drupal!

Comment: its not really important, put it in last.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked was adding the following to .bash_profile.

```
alias composer="/ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli ~/common/composer.phar"
export DRUSH_PHP=/ramdisk/php/54/bin/php54-cli
alias drush=”~/.composer/vendor/bin/drush”
```